# How calculate the route in here api?

Tags: javascript, here-api

Faced a problem. I'm studying here api and for educational purposes I want to make me calculate the distance between points along the route. I found a tutorial on YouTube, implemented it, but the map does not work + swears at the getPosition method. the map is no longer displayed. What am I doing wrong, I've been sitting for 3 days and it doesn't work. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgq3hF1cAbY I study this video
My code

```
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  apikey: '56dGHQzUA0O3ORkDIemoGeeI1sK8kwi-9owuL5cj8xg'
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

var map = new H.Map(
        document.getElementById('map'),
        defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,{
          center: {lat: 53.8771011, lng: 27.6166123},
          zoom: 14,
          pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
        });
window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());
const routingService = platform.getRoutingService();
const tracyMarker = new H.map.Marker({lat: 53.8771011, lng: 27.6166123});
const stocktonMarker = new H.map.Marker({lat: 53.90374, lng: 27.56546});
const straightLine = new H.geo.LineString();
straightLine.pushPoint(tracyMarker.getPosition());
straightLine.pushPoint(stocktonMarker.getPosition());
const straightPolyline = new H.map().Polyline(
        straightLine,
        {
          style:{
            lineWidth: 5
          }
        }
);
const params = {
  mode: "fastest;car;traffic:enabled",
  waypoint0: "53.8771011,27.6166123",
  waypoint1: "53.90374,27.56546",
  representation: "display",
  routeAttributes: "summary"
};
routingService.calculateRoute(params, success => {
  console.log(success.response.route[0].summary.distamce);
  const routeLineString = new H.geo.LineString();
  success.response.route[0].shape.forEach(point => {
    const [lat, lng] = point.split(",");
    routeLineString.pushPoint({
      lat: lat,
      lng: lng
    });
    });
  const routePolyline = new H.map.Polyline(
          routeLineString,
          {
            style: {
              lineWidth: 5
            }
          }
  );
  map.addObject(routePolyline);
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
});

map.addObject([tracyMarker, stocktonMarker, straightPolyline]);

const distance = tracyMarker.getPosition().distance(stocktonMarker.getPosition());
 console.log(distance);

var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

var ui = H.ui.UI.creat
```

eDefault(map, defaultLayers);

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the below documentations to calculate the distance between points along the route.

Example for a request a driving route from A to B and display it on the map

This example calculates the fastest car route from the Brandenburg Gate in the centre of Berlin (52.51605°N, 13.37787°E) to Friedrichstraße Railway Station (52.52058°N, 13.38615°E), and displays it on the map.

```
/**
 * Calculates and displays a car route from the Brandenburg Gate in the centre of Berlin
 * to Friedrichstraße Railway Station.
 *
 * A full list of available request parameters can be found in the Routing API documentation.
 * see: http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/resource-calculate-route.html
 *
 * @param {H.service.Platform} platform A stub class to access HERE services
 */
function calculateRouteFromAtoB(platform) {
  var router = platform.getRoutingService(null, 8),
      routeRequestParams = {
        routingMode: 'fast',
        transportMode: 'car',
        origin: '52.5160,13.3779', // Brandenburg Gate
        destination: '52.5206,13.3862', // Friedrichstraße Railway Station
        return: 'polyline,turnByTurnActions,actions,instructions,travelSummary'
      };

  router.calculateRoute(
    routeRequestParams,
    onSuccess,
    onError
  );
}

/**
 * This function will be called once the Routing REST API provides a response
 * @param {Object} result A JSONP object representing the calculated route
 *
 * see: http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/resource-type-calculate-route.html
 */
function onSuccess(result) {
  var route = result.routes[0];

  /*
   * The styling of the route response on the map is entirely under the developer's control.
   * A representative styling can be found the full JS + HTML code of this example
   * in the functions below:
   */
  addRouteShapeToMap(route);
  addManueversToMap(route);
  addWaypointsToPanel(route);
  addManueversToPanel(route);
  addSummaryToPanel(route);
  // ... etc.
}

/**
 * This function will be called if a communication error occurs during the JSON-P request
 * @param {Object} error The error message received.
 */
function onError(error) {
  alert('Can\'t reach the remote server');
}

/**
 * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
 */

// set up containers for the map + panel
var mapContainer = document.getElementById('map'),
  routeInstructionsContainer = document.getElementById('panel');

// Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
// In your own code, replace variable window.apikey with your own apikey
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  apikey: window.apikey
});

var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

// Step 2: initialize a map - this map is centered over Berlin
var map = new H.Map(mapContainer,
  defaultLayers.vector.normal.map, {
  center: {lat: 52.5160, lng: 13.3779},
  zoom: 13,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});

// add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());

// Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Create the default UI components
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

// Hold a reference to any infobubble opened
var bubble;

/**
 * Opens/Closes a infobubble
 * @param {H.geo.Point} position The location on the map.
 * @param {String} text          The contents of the infobubble.
 */
function openBubble(position, text) {
  if (!bubble) {
    bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble(
      position,
      // The FO property holds the province name.
      {content: text});
    ui.addBubble(bubble);
  } else {
    bubble.setPosition(position);
    bubble.setContent(text);
    bubble.open();
  }
}

/**
 * Creates a H.map.Polyline from the shape of the route and adds it to the map.
 * @param {Object} route A route as received from the H.service.RoutingService
 */
function addRouteShapeToMap(route) {
  route.sections.forEach((section) => {
    // decode LineString from the flexible polyline
    let linestring = H.geo.LineString.fromFlexiblePolyline(section.polyline);

    // Create a polyline to display the route:
    let polyline = new H.map.Polyline(linestring, {
      style: {
        lineWidth: 4,
        strokeColor: 'rgba(0, 128, 255, 0.7)'
      }
    });

    // Add the polyline to the map
    map.addObject(polyline);
    // And zoom to its bounding rectangle
    map.getViewModel().setLookAtData({
      bounds: polyline.getBoundingBox()
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Creates a series of H.map.Marker points from the route and adds them to the map.
 * @param {Object} route A route as received from the H.service.RoutingService
 */
function addManueversToMap(route) {
  var svgMarkup = '<svg width="18" height="18" ' +
    'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' +
    '<circle cx="8" cy="8" r="8" ' +
      'fill="#1b468d" stroke="white" stroke-width="1" />' +
    '</svg>',
    dotIcon = new H.map.Icon(svgMarkup, {anchor: {x:8, y:8}}),
    group = new H.map.Group(),
    i,
    j;

  route.sections.forEach((section) => {
    let poly = H.geo.LineString.fromFlexiblePolyline(section.polyline).getLatLngAltArray();

    let actions = section.actions;
    // Add a marker for each maneuver
    for (i = 0; i < actions.length; i += 1) {
      let action = actions[i];
      var marker = new H.map.Marker({
        lat: poly[action.offset * 3],
        lng: poly[action.offset * 3 + 1]},
        {icon: dotIcon});
      marker.instruction = action.instruction;
      group.addObject(marker);
    }

    group.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
      map.setCenter(evt.target.getGeometry());
      openBubble(evt.target.getGeometry(), evt.target.instruction);
    }, false);

    // Add the maneuvers group to the map
    map.addObject(group);
  });
}

/**
 * Creates a series of H.map.Marker points from the route and adds them to the map.
 * @param {Object} route A route as received from the H.service.RoutingService
 */
function addWaypointsToPanel(route) {
  var nodeH3 = document.createElement('h3'),
    labels = [];

  route.sections.forEach((section) => {
    labels.push(
      section.turnByTurnActions[0].nextRoad.name[0].value)
    labels.push(
      section.turnByTurnActions[section.turnByTurnActions.length - 1].currentRoad.name[0].value)
  });

  nodeH3.textContent = labels.join(' - ');
  routeInstructionsContainer.innerHTML = '';
  routeInstructionsContainer.appendChild(nodeH3);
}

/**
 * Creates a series of H.map.Marker points from the route and adds them to the map.
 * @param {Object} route A route as received from the H.service.RoutingService
 */
function addSummaryToPanel(route) {
  let duration = 0,
    distance = 0;

  route.sections.forEach((section) => {
    distance += section.travelSummary.length;
    duration += section.travelSummary.duration;
  });

  var summaryDiv = document.createElement('div'),
    content = '<b>Total distance</b>: ' + distance + 'm. <br />' +
      '<b>Travel Time</b>: ' + toMMSS(duration) + ' (in current traffic)';

  summaryDiv.style.fontSize = 'small';
  summaryDiv.style.marginLeft = '5%';
  summaryDiv.style.marginRight = '5%';
  summaryDiv.innerHTML = content;
  routeInstructionsContainer.appendChild(summaryDiv);
}

/**
 * Creates a series of H.map.Marker points from the route and adds them to the map.
 * @param {Object} route A route as received from the H.service.RoutingService
 */
function addManueversToPanel(route) {
  var nodeOL = document.createElement('ol');

  nodeOL.style.fontSize = 'small';
  nodeOL.style.marginLeft ='5%';
  nodeOL.style.marginRight ='5%';
  nodeOL.className = 'directions';

  route.sections.forEach((section) => {
    section.actions.forEach((action, idx) => {
      var li = document.createElement('li'),
        spanArrow = document.createElement('span'),
        spanInstruction = document.createElement('span');

      spanArrow.className = 'arrow ' + (action.direction || '') + action.action;
      spanInstruction.innerHTML = section.actions[idx].instruction;
      li.appendChild(spanArrow);
      li.appendChild(spanInstruction);

      nodeOL.appendChild(li);
    });
  });

  routeInstructionsContainer.appendChild(nodeOL);
}

function toMMSS(duration) {
  return Math.floor(duration / 60) + ' minutes ' + (duration % 60) + ' seconds.';
}

// Now use the map as required...
calculateRouteFromAtoB(platform);
```

See also full example [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/services/map-with-route-from-a-to-b)

A basic route request consists of an origin, departure, and transportMode. The resulting response will contain a list of routes. The list may be empty if no routes were possible.

The origin and destination can be a latitude and longitude pairs and represent the beginning and end of the requested route.

transportMode controls what mode of transport is used for the route. pedestrian, car, truck, bicycle and scooter are currently available.

If the request specifies alternatives, the response may provide additional routes.

If the request specifies return with summary or travelSummary, then the sections will provide additional summary information such as length and duration.

A route will include one or more sections.

In case that no route is possible, an empty list of routes and a notice will be returned.

curl -X GET 
'https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?transportMode=car&origin=52.5308,13.3847&destination=52.5323,13.3789&return=summary&apikey={YOUR_API_KEY}'

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "id": "bfaed7d0-19c7-4e72-81b7-24eeb148b62b",
      "sections": [
        {
          "arrival": {
            "place": {
              "location": {
                "lat": 52.53232637420297,
                "lng": 13.378873988986016
              },
              "type": "place"
            },
            "time": "2019-12-09T16:05:05+01:00"
          },
          "departure": {
            "place": {
              "location": {
                "lat": 52.53098367713392,
                "lng": 13.384566977620125
              },
              "type": "place"
            },
            "time": "2019-12-09T16:03:02+01:00"
          },
          "id": "85357f8f-00ad-447e-a510-d8c02e0b264f",
          "summary": {
            "duration": 123,
            "length": 538
          },
          "transport": {
            "mode": "car"
          },
          "type": "vehicle"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

See further documentation [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/use-cases/calculate-route.html)